# Read previous/next line of text file with fs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

I was wondering if it was at all possible to read the very last line of a text file. And then, read the one before that. I can see all the data in the `console`, but I have no idea how to just display *one* line.

Currently, I am using `fs` and `byline`, to write and read files, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `readline` core module instead of `byline`, and keep track of the current and previous lines when you receive events.

```
var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('input.file')
});

var current = "";
var prev = "";

rl.on('line', function (line) {
  prev = current;
  current = line;
});

rl.on('close', function () {
  console.log('Last line:', current);
  console.log('Prev line:', prev);
});
```

Alternatively, just read the whole file into a string and then split it after line breaks.

Comment: Just tried this out and it works! Would you happen to know how I would get the next line, if it exists?

Comment: not sure what you mean by next line...in which context?

Comment: I took your code and used prev to "Go Back" (I'm making a web browser in Electron). That works, but I'm not sure how to "Go Forward". I feel like I may actually need to change the way I'm doing this, to get the desired functionality to work, like using JSON to iterate back and forth over an array.

Comment: I agree, you probably need to use some stack for that...or maybe 2 stacks, one for back and one for forward.

Comment: Haha, oh well. I'll update my question with my solution when I figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help and advice.